# instance.__dict__ & class.__dict__

Tags: python, attributes

Code goes first:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        self.foo = 'foo'
    def bar(self):
        self.bar = 'bar'

cls_dict = dict(A.__dict__)  #not empty

a = A()
a_dict = dict(a.__dict__)  #empty, why?
```

Comment: http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#the-dynamic-dict explains it pretty well: `__dict__` only contains attributes directly "on" the object.

Comment: firstly, what did you expect to be in there?

Comment: @li.davidm, `directly on the object`? Those attr defined in the class doesn't count?

Comment: @Alcott: No, since those are "separate" (in a sense). Both classes and instances are objects, and an instance can replace attributes defined on the object, so they're separate. The page I linked to is much more articulate.

Answer (score 12):

In Python, everything is an object containing attributes. That includes **classes themselves**. The whole object-oriented thing with classes which define methods and instances which can execute those methods with the varying data per-instance is just a protocol for looking up attributes in a series of objects.

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        self.foo = 'foo'
    def bar(self):
        self.bar = 'bar'
```

This creates a class object, bound to the name `A`. That object contains two attributes, `foo` and `bar`, each bound to method objects.

```
a = A()
```

This creates an object bound to the name `a`, which is an instance of `A`. It contains no attributes at all, yet. But the fact that it is an instance of `A` means the "lookup protocol" when you ask for `a.foo` is to first look for an attribute on `a`, then if that fails look for an attribute on `A`. This is how all instances of `A` can access the same set of methods.

In Python, also, you can create attributes on (almost) any object at any time. All it requires is `some_object.some_attribute = some_value`. Until you do that, the attribute does not exist. So with actually calling `a.foo()` or `a.bar()`, those `foo` and `bar` attributes do not exist in `a` (neither do any other attributes your program may or may not one day add to that object), which is why `a.__dict__` is empty at the point where you called it. If you expect 'default' values of `foo` and `bar` to exist on every object, you need to say so by setting those values in the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 0):

`a.__dict__` is empty because none of the attributes have been initialized on the instance as there's no `__init__()` defined. Meanwhile, a class is an object, and it has initialized some attributes.

```
>>> A
<class '__main__.A'>
```