# How to interpret the documentation on LinearSegmentedColormap

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I got this example code using LinearSegmentedColormap that I cannot understand.

`type(cmap)` gives `matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap`

`cmap.__dict__` gives

```
 'name': 'jet',
 'N': 256,
 '_rgba_bad': (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
 '_rgba_under': None,
 '_rgba_over': None,
 '_i_under': 256,
 '_i_over': 257,
 '_i_bad': 258,
 '_isinit': False,
 'colorbar_extend': False,
 '_segmentdata': {'red': ((0.0, 0, 0),
   (0.35, 0, 0),
   (0.66, 1, 1),
   (0.89, 1, 1),
   (1, 0.5, 0.5)),
  'green': ((0.0, 0, 0),
   (0.125, 0, 0),
   (0.375, 1, 1),
   (0.64, 1, 1),
   (0.91, 0, 0),
   (1, 0, 0)),
  'blue': ((0.0, 0.5, 0.5),
   (0.11, 1, 1),
   (0.34, 1, 1),
   (0.65, 0, 0),
   (1, 0, 0))},
 '_gamma': 1.0}
```

while `LinearSegmentedColormap.__dict__` gives

```
              '__doc__': '\n    Colormap objects based on lookup tables using linear segments.\n\n    The lookup table is generated using linear interpolation for each\n    primary color, with the 0-1 domain divided into any number of\n    segments.\n    ',
              '__init__': <function matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.__init__(self, name, segmentdata, N=256, gamma=1.0)>,
              '_init': <function matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap._init(self)>,
              'set_gamma': <function matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.set_gamma(self, gamma)>,
              'from_list': <staticmethod at 0x1bc1ae2b5c0>,
              '_resample': <function matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap._resample(self, lutsize)>,
              'reversed': <function matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.reversed(self, name=None)>})
```

Isn't `cmap` an instance of `LinearSegmentedColormap`? And in such case why does it's attributes and functions not correspond to the ones in the class `LinearSegmentedColormap`?

The other question is what is happening when the line:

```
colors = cmap(np.arange(cmap.N))
```

is run? I suppose one of the class methods are being run but which? And is it possible form the documentation of `LinearSegmentedColormap` to figure out what is happening?

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap  
import matplotlib as plt  
import numpy as np  

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet')  
type(cmap)  
cmap.**__dict__**  
colors = cmap(np.arange(cmap.N))  

LinearSegmentedColormap.__dict__
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question about the difference between the class `__dict__` and the instance `__dict__` may already be answered in [instance.__dict__ & class.__dict__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720611/instance-dict-class-dict) or [dict in Python object instance doesn't contain the methods of the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490401/dict-in-python-object-instance-doesnt-contain-the-methods-of-the-class). In any case they are different, and the instance `__dict__` does not contain all the class attributes.

It seems the heart of the question though is to find out what happens if you call the class instance.

You can call any instance that has a `__call__` method. In case of the colormaps, [`LinearSegmentedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html) subclasses the base [`Colormap`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html). `Colormap` has a [`__call__`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/ac0a423c79acbe2993160501ce0ed028e42a23fc/lib/matplotlib/colors.py#L514) method. It takes in a (list of) number(s) and returns a (list of) color(s).

> And is it possible form the documentation of LinearSegmentedColormap to figure out what is happening?

Unfortunately, it seems not the case. Probably there should be a sentence explaining it in the [`matplotlib.colors`](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) documentation, as well as in each of the `Colormap` subclasses.
 Improvements of the documentation are always welcome.